# Discord.js, Toggling commands

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

so I want to toggle command using a command. e.g `?command toggle (name)`. I've been thinking of using a database and getting the guild and the commands available and then it checks if it is disabled when doing the command on the action. I don't know how to approach this tho. Any help? Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by using a database and something along these lines. Use these as guidelines when making your own, the following code hasn't been tested, ill leave the rest up to you.

```js
var mysql = require("mysql")
var prefix = "!"

// con == connection to database


// on message
if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

let [command, ...args] = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/\s+/g)
var disabled = false;

con.query(`SELECT * FROM commandsettings WHERE command = ${command}`, (err, rows) {
    if (err) return console.err(err);
    if (!rows) return;

    disabled = rows[0].toggled
})

if (disabled === true) return;


// command handler
if (command == "toggle") {
    con.query(`SELECT * FROM commandsettings WHERE command = '${args[0]}'`, (err, rows) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err)
        if (!rows) return console.error("NO ROWS FOUND")

        var toggleto = (args[1] || rows[0].toggled ? false : true)

        con.query(`UPDATE commandsettings SET toggled = '${toggleto}' WHERE command = '${args[0]}`, (err) => {
            if (err) console.error(err)
        })

        message.channel.send(`Toggled Command "${command}" to "${toggleto ? "Enabled" : "Disabled"} "`)

    })
}
```